# FQL Error: requires extended permission: read_stream

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

Today I started get some strange FQL Error.

FQL query: *SELECT target_id FROM connection WHERE source_id = user_id1 AND target_id = user_id2*
*SELECT uid FROM user WHERE has_added_app=1 and uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = "user_id")*

FQL Response (Error):  Error: Requires extended permission: read_stream

What is it???

Help.

Comment: Same thing with US using fql and the facebook API. I'll stay tuned

Answer (score 1):

According to their [Change Log](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/changelog/), on 2011-09-18, Facebook pushed this update:

> FQL connection table now requires read_stream permission. (rE435878)

I had the same problem. I was only using the `connection` table to get a list of friends, so I was able to change to the `friend` table to pull the info I needed.

Stuff like this is what makes Facebook Platform a hostile development environment.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like facebook has changed some of the required permissions for some actions this night. The same happened to me. You need to ask for read_stream permissions. For more information refer [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/)

P.S: You might need to remove the application from your profile and add it again with the new permissions